# setHint doesnt work with setInputType

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

I build EditText dynamically. Among other things, I set 2 properties: hint(.setHint) and inputType(.setInputType). My problem: when I invoke setInputType, setHint has no effect: blank edittexts remain blank with no hint. Once I comment out setInputType, I see all hints. I need both input type and hint. What to do? My code:

```
    private EditText buildTextBox(Property property)
{
    EditText control = new EditText(this);
    control.setInputType(getInputTypeByPropertyInputType(property.getType()));// android.text.InputType.
    control.setHint(property.getDisplayName());
    return control;
}

private int getInputTypeByPropertyInputType(String type)
{
    if (type.equals("integer"))
    {
        return android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
    }
    else
    {
        return android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
    }
}
```

Comment: One of methods I called was control.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) - once I removed this call, I was able to see all the hints. I cant explain why it happens and to my mind this is pretty strange behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Eugene 
Ensure you call control.SetHint() just before you call the control.setGravity() and control.setInputType(); and it works for me verrry much!

```
            column1 = new EditText(this);
            column1.setId(i);
            column1.setHint("Value");
            column1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            column1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Eugene.
Remove the gravity(just don't use CENTER) and the hint texts will come back as normal.
Nice find!